# SSRS with Azure Sql DWH

Tags: reporting-services, azure-sql-database

I am new to Azure and i need to know

Can We use SQL Server Reporting Service with Azure SQL Data Warehouse (as a data source)?

Big Appreciation for answering

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Establish a connection to your Azure SQL Data Warehouse as [if it were an Azure SQL DB](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519560.aspx).

If you write your own SQL queries for your report, ensure that it uses [T-SQL that is supported on Azure SQL Data Warehouse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-reference-tsql-statements).

**Note**: I have *not* verified whether the SSRS Report Builder tool generated T-SQL generates only SQL Data Warehouse T-SQL compatible statements.